# How can I make InternalsVisibleTo attribute work by signing a public token key safely?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, internalsvisibleto

I am trying to expose some internals to my unit test project by using:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTest")]
```

But I am getting the error:

> Error 1   Friend assembly reference MyTest' is invalid. Strong-name
>   signed assemblies must specify a public key in their
>   InternalsVisibleTo declarations.  .../MyClass.cs...

When I assign a PublicTokenKey manually:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTest, PublicKeyToken=XxxxxYysakf")]
```

The solution builds without any error.

1. Why do I need to include a public key token?
2. I am not sure if I will break something in production by including the public key token.

So, **what is the best and safest way to assign an public key to my Test project?**

Comment: You shouldnt need to assign a public key token. But you need to make sure that the assembly names match.

Comment: I am copy pasting the assembly names from the Assembly Name field shown in Project properties. So it should be correct, I gues..

Comment: Alright, so i havent encountered that issue myself, but this guy here might have another option for you http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/04/unit-tests-and-internalsvisibleto.html

Comment: The solution builds without errors when you use PublicKeyToken, but Intellisense might give you a hint that the assembly reference couldn't be resolved.

Answer (score 7):

*I am surprised that `PublicKeyToken` even works - on my machine it forces me to use `PublicKey`*

1. The reason that you need a public key token is because strongly-named assemblies can be put into the GAC - which has high trust. It would be a security hole if any assembly called 'MyTest' (that is potentially untrusted - e.g. a control in the browser) could call into the internals of a GACed assembly; it wants the public key to prevent this type of hack.
2. This shouldn't break anything in production - even if the assembly cannot be found. This attribute is used during compile-time and not runtime.

**What is the safest way?**

If you are really worried about it breaking production code, remove the attribute during release builds:

```
#if (DEBUG || TEST)
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTest, PublicKeyToken=XxxxxYysakf")] 
#endif
```

If you have a few projects that need the public key token (and you have a single key pair, which you should) you could also define a file such as `AssemblyInfo.global.cs` and add it as a linked file to all your projects:

```
class KeyTokens
{
   public const string Global = ", PublicKeyToken=XxxxxYysakf";
}
```

This simplifies things to (especially if you need to use the `PublicKey` which is **really** long):

```
#if (DEBUG || TEST)
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyTest" + KeyTokens.Global)] 
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("HisTest" + KeyTokens.Global)] 
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TheirTest" + KeyTokens.Global)] 
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the concatentation approach prevents IntelliSense from working in the "friend" VS project (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542121/intellisense-warns-red-sqiggle-incorrectly-for-internalsvisibleattribute-set-by-a-constant, https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/108537/internalsvisibleto-intellisense-signed-assemblies).  Until/unless this is fixed, the concatenated constant approach is unlikely to find favour with most potential users.

Comment: @Nicole - strange it works for me, possibly because we reference the assemblies by output file here and not project.

Comment: It only affects project references. Unfortunately, the scenarios where friend assemblies tend to be most useful (semi-private APIs, exposing internals for testing) are also scenarios where folks tend to prefer to use in-solution project references.